# ZF2: Critical config differences between dev and prod

Tags: php, security, zend-framework2

I have been developing a ZF2 application and am now ready to trial it in production (an alpha version, anyhow).  What are the critical configuration differences I need to be thinking about?

For example:

- The skeleton application already takes care of PHP's `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings (i.e. it doesn't set them on because the `APP_ENVIRONMENT` is not 'development'
- It seems that, in the `module.config.php` file I need to set `display_not_found_reason` and `display_exceptions` to false

What other zend-specific setting do I need to think about?

I'm not concerned with non-critical settings such as db credentials, mainly just security related ones.

As a side issue, should I be concerned that turning off `display_not_found_reason` and `display_exceptions` settings could be overwritten by another module?  And should I be putting these settings in the top-level `application.config.php` file to protect against this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you have to change are settings that post information about your setup and settings to the screen. Such as errors/exceptions and display not_found_reasons but you already covered that in your question.

You should also check that there are no development modules active such as ZendDevelopersTools and that the modules you installed don't have a dev mode enabled. Otherwise they may post fatal information about your app to your users.

You should not be concerned that your settings in the default Application modules is going to be overridden. Because those settings should never be overridden from any module and any module that does that has probably already been fixed.